# UIKeyboard notification handler triggered 3 times

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

My code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void)handleKeyboard:(NSNotification*)notification {
  NSLog(@"triggered");
}
```

See:

[image]

The disappearing handler is triggered once as normal, but 3 times when appears. Is this a iOS bug?

Comment: Use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` name instead. Could help.

Comment: @antonio Tried, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not helpful for your problem but you need to be calling `[super viewWill…` for your overrides.

`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

`-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

From the docs.

> If you override this method, you must call super at some point in
>   your implementation.